# Using grease/tampermonkey (or another extension) to omit certain characters inside web elements

Tags: javascript, css

Firstly, I apologize if my terminology here isn't the most accurate; I'm very much a novice when it comes to programming. A forum I frequent has added a bunch of unneccessary, "glitchy" images and text to the page as a part of some promotion, but the result is that the forum is now difficult to use and read. I was able to script out most of it using adblock, but there's one last bit that shows up inside the forum elements themselves, and adblock wants to remove the whole element (which breaks the forum). This is part of the code in question, with the URLs changed:

```
<td class="windowbg" valign="middle" width="42%">&blk34;&blk34;&blk34;&blk34;&blk34;
        <a href="http://www.example.com">Thread title</a>  <span class="smalltext"></span><img src="example.com/forumicon.gif"></td>
```

As you can see, the ▓ character shows up a bunch of times for no reason. Is there a way to make my browser ignore this character when it's inside of an element? If there's a way to do this using AdBlock, I am not smart enough to see it.

Comment: Yes there is a way using grease/tampermonkey. Find the element and remove it.

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, removing the element breaks the forum. I only need to remove the "&blk34;" / "▓" character. Not the whole <td>

Edit: I might be making a mistake with my terminology here. I understand the "element" to be the things inside of <td>, and a "character" to be an individual letter, number, or symbol.

Comment: With element I was referring to whatever you want to remove. Be it an HTM element, a character or whatever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it, using a [NodeIterator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeIterator):

```
var iter = document.createNodeIterator( document.body, NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT );
var node;
while (node = iter.nextNode()) {
    node.textContent = node.textContent.replace( /[\u2580-\u259f]+/g, '' );
}
```

This is just plain JavaScript code; you can paste it into the Firefox / Chrome JS console to test it.  The regexp `/[\u2580-\u259f]+/` matches any sequence of characters in the ["Block Elements" Unicode block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_Elements), including U+2593 Dark Shade (▓).  You may want to tweak the regexp to match the characters you want to remove.  (Tip: If you don't know what the codes for those characters are, copy and paste them into the "UTF8 String" box on [this page](http://www.isthisthingon.org/unicode/).)

Ps. If these characters that you want to remove occur only in a certain part of the document, you can make this code a bit more efficient by replacing the root node (document.body above) with the specific DOM node that you want to remove the characters from.  To find the nodes you want, you can use e.g. [document.getElementById()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) or, more generally, [document.querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) (or even [document.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) and loop over the results).